# laravel - use Request class or input class

Tags: php, api, rest, laravel

In a  restful controller, which class should I use to get passed variables?

```
$member->email = Input::get('email');
// or
$member->email = Request::get('email');
```

both options work for me, but whats the difference?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Input::get()` is just a helper that maps to the Request class. It doesn't really matter which you use.

Comment: In Laravel 5, Input::all() and Request::all() are different. You'll notice when using HMVC Input gives current input and Request gives the original request entire input.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Request is preferred in the context of a restful controller.

Answer (score 0):

With Laravel 3 i prefer to use:

```
$member->email = Input::get('email');
```

But with Laravel 4 I prefer to use:

```
$member->email = Request::get('email');
```

Please check the article:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/laravel-4-a-start-at-a-restful-api/