# What is difference between Input::all() and request()->all() in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, request

I often see examples where gets data using `Input::all()` or `request()->all()` or 
instanse of Request `$request->all()`.

What is difference between of these?

Where does need to use Input and where does need to use Request?

What is the best practice? Somebody can explain it?

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670397/laravel-use-request-class-or-input-class

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29960463/laravel-input-facade-vs-request-facade